# How to open ionic sidemenu like a Google Play APP sidemenu

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic App and When I Click navigation icon then navigation icon

shift right side and all sidemenu show in left sidebar.But I open any app like

Google Play when I click its navigation icon then sidemenu shift left to right.

How can I do same in ionic app.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour is from left to right. It can be checked at the docs:

[https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/)

Nevertheless, it can be modified with `side` attribute:

`<ion-menu side="left" [content]="mycontent">...</ion-menu>`

**UPDATE: Ionic 1**

For Overlaying side menu:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-ion-drawer

Try it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRLqwW

Comment: I am using ionic1 and there is not <ion-menu > tag

Comment: If you are not using the latest version of the framework, include that at your question. On the other hand, if you are not using a standard component, could you provide your custom code?

Comment: <ion-side-menu side="left"> for ionic 1

Comment: <ion-side-menu side="left"> it is by default in  ionic 1  but I want overlay design

Comment: I have updated the answer, use `ionic-ion-drawer`. Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRLqwW